# Para que serve a classe EmptyIterator?

Tags: php, iterator, spliterator

Na documentação do `PHP`, tem uma classe chamada [`EmptyIterator`](http://php.net/emptyiterator)

Quando olho a documentação do método [`EmptyIterator::rewind()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/emptyiterator.rewind.php), lá está escrito:

> No operation, nothing to do. (Nenhuma operação, nada a fazer)

E os outros métodos lançam exceções ou retornam `FALSE`.

Qual é o objetivo de se ter um `iterator` vazio no manual? Pois, se eu tivesse que estender essa classe, os métodos herdados não serviriam para nada !?!?

Comment: Ah, já sei: Não serve pra nada.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762768/what-is-the-purpose-of-emptyiterator

Comment: Porquê não respondes a pergunta, e aceitas a resposta, visto que já sabes qual é ?

Comment: obrigado, @Edilson. Quando eu tiver tempo eu faço isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que a solução para essa pergunta pode ser encontrada nessa resposta dada pelo @Maniero, aqui no SOPT, [Pra que serve o padrão Null Object?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88743/4995)

Provavelmente o `EmptyIterator` foi criado como uma forma de fazer esse objeto atenderem os requisitos da interface `Iterator`, sem realizar nenhuma operação com os métodos de contrato.

Ou seja, se encaixaria perfeitamente no *pattern* Null Object.

Exemplo:

```
function required_iterator(Iterator $it)
{
   // Faz um paranauê aqui
}


required_iterator(new ArrayIterator([1, 2, 3]))

//Atende o requisito da função: Uma classe que implemente iterator

required_iterator(new EmptyIterator);
```

É um exemplo muito simples, que não mostra totalmente a eficácia desse método, mas que exemplifica o que o padrão Null Object representa.

Comment: +1 para o @bigown, mesmo que ele não tenha respondido aqui :_: