# Pra que serve o padrão Null Object?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

Fiz essa pergunta [What is the purpose of EmptyIterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762768/what-is-the-purpose-of-emptyiterator) no SOEN, porque não encontrei respostas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67285/para-que-serve-a-classe-emptyiterator).

Daí me falaram em uma resposta do SOEN de um padrão chamado `Null Object`.

Qual é a finalidade desse padrão e como ele funciona?

Comment: Eu não conheço com detalhes, mas eu pensaria que ele tem a mesma finalidade dos "elementos neutros" na adição e multiplicação (`0` e `1`), ou talvez da "matriz identidade": quando seu código precisa fazer uma operação, mas você não quer que nada aconteça (mas sem ter que criar um `if` pra tratar desse caso especial), você usa esse valor "que não serve pra nada". É um pouco também como as funções "no-op" (nenhuma operação), que existem só pra preencher um buraco. O interessante nesses casos é que o código fica idêntico exista alguma operação útil acontecendo ou não.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É um objeto criado para simular outro objeto com os mesmos contratos, mas sem funcionalidade alguma. Sem estado e sem comportamento real. Os dois tipos são compatíveis entre si já que atendem o mesmo contrato, implementam as mesmas interfaces e possivelmente estendem o mesmo tipo.

É uma forma de evitar o uso do estado nulo de objetos que a maioria das linguagens usam. Quando realmente existe uma necessidade semântica, uma situação que um objeto de um tipo seja nulo, você usa este objeto que atende os mesmos contratos mas não faz nada.

Esta forma tende ser "mais orientada a objeto" por fornecer uma melhor abstração para uma situação de valor desconhecido, evita efeitos colaterais e facilita a codificação que não precisa tratar casos específicos como exceção à regra.

Há um pouco de controvérsia sobre seu uso já que ele também pode acabar escondendo alguns erros de programação que seriam pegos se usasse um valor nulo, que seria um tipo completamente diferente e incompatível.

A crítica ocorre porque apesar de estar cumprindo o contrato, faz algo inesperado. E olha que tem gente que critica outros recursos como a sobrecarga de operadores porque alguém **pode** fazer uma subtração no operador de adição. Neste caso é certo que o método faz algo diferente do esperado. Achar erro de lógica é muito mais difícil que achar erro de programação. E este padrão induz ao erro de lógica. Por isto é raro ver ele sendo usado. E mais raro ainda compêndios de padrões de projeto citando ele.

Melhorando o exemplo da resposta no SO:

```php
interface IAnimal {
    public function makeSound();
}

class Dog implements IAnimal {
    public function makeSound() { 
        echo "Woof.."; 
    }
}

class Cat implements IAnimal {
    public function makeSound() { 
        echo "Meowww.."; 
    }
}

class NullAnimal implements IAnimal {
    public function makeSound() { 
        // silence...
    }
}

$animalType = 'elephant';
switch($animalType) {
    case 'dog':
        $animal = new Dog();
        break;
    case 'cat':
        $animal = new Cat();
        break;
    default:
        $animal = new NullAnimal();
        break;
}
$animal->makeSound(); // ..the null animal makes no sound

function Exemplo(IAnimal $animal) {
    $animal->makeSound();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/NullObject.php).

Há casos que é preciso tratar a condição de forma especial. Aí acaba dando quase no mesmo que usar um `null`. Só que há separação do código, o que é bom para alguns e ruim para outros. Então teria que fazer o seguinte:

```php
function Exemplo(NullAnimal $animal) {
    echo "não para para fazer nada com este objeto";
}
```

Comment: Eu pensaria em algo como lançar uma exceção, se fosse no caso do exemplo que o cara postou no SOEN

Comment: É uma possibilidade mas a ideia do padrão não é bem esta já que acabaria fazendo a mesma coisa que aconteceria se usasse um `null`. Não digo que não tem vantagem alguma, mas a ideia não é essa. Eu continuaria usando `null` na maioria das situações. Ainda que eu evitaria situações que precisa de um `null` para dar alguma semântica especial ao objeto.

Comment: quando vejo esse pattern lembro de placas de vídeo. É como se os jogos tivesse uma interface que obrigasse a implementação de recursos. Essa classe NullObject seria como uma placa de vídeo simulada (ou um computador que não tenha uma placa de vídeo, e o VGA seria como esse NULLOBJECT). Se eu viajei, pode zoar

Comment: Traduzindo a minha maneira: É uma forma de fazer os objetos atenderem os requisitos de uma interface, sem realizar nenhuma operação com os métodos de contrato :)

Comment: Não, porque isto estaria dizendo que a placa de vídeo não faz nada. Na verdade a placa de vídeo simulada teria que fazer alguma, reproduzir o comportamento esperado. A segunda afirmação é verdadeira.

Comment: Acho que estou com saudade de jogar no pc :). Que  afirmação viajada - a primeira. Mas se a segunda está certa, então entendi a linha de raciocinio.