# Correção no Construtor da Classe Java para atender ao Sonar

Tags: java, construtor

Estou precisando corrigir algumas divergências no Sonar. Tenho esses construtores, *getters* e *setters*:

```
public EmpregadoContrato() {
    // construtor padrão
}

public EmpregadoContrato(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public Contrato getContrato() {
    return contrato;
}

public void setContrato(Contrato contrato) {
    this.contrato = contrato;
}
```

Como faço para corrigir este Construtor que está acusando erro no Sonar:

```
public EmpregadoContrato(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Erro:

> "contrato" is marked "javax.validation.constraints.NotNull" but is not initialized in this constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se `contrato` foi marcado com a anotação [`@NotNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html), então quer dizer que esse campo não pode ser nulo.

Mas nos seus construtores, ou você só seta o `id`, ou não seta nenhum dos campos (no construtor padrão). Como `contrato` não é setado em nenhum deles, então ele será nulo - que é justamente o que ele não pode ser, pois foi marcado como `@NotNull`.

Sendo assim, você poderia remover os dois construtores (o padrão e o que recebe o `id`) e deixar apenas este:

```
public EmpregadoContrato(Integer id, Contrato contrato) {
    this.id = id;
    this.contrato = contrato;
}
```

Reflita: se `contrato` não pode ser `null`, faz sentido ter construtores que criam um `EmpregadoContrato` com `contrato` nulo? Ambos os construtores que você tem criam esta situação (`contrato` nulo), então ou esses construtores devem ser removidos, ou talvez o campo possa ser nulo.

Se o campo pode ser nulo, remova a anotação `@NotNull`.

Se o campo realmente não pode ser nulo, então não faz sentido ter construtores que não setam nenhum valor a este campo.

Claro que isso não impede alguém de tentar fazer `new EmpregadoContrato(1, null)`, mas neste caso bastaria incluir uma validação no construtor. Por exemplo:

```
public EmpregadoContrato(Integer id, Contrato contrato) {
    this.id = id;
    if (contrato == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("contrato não pode ser nulo");
    }
    this.contrato = contrato;
}
```

Outra opção é usar [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-), a diferença é que este método lança um `NullPointerException` caso o valor seja nulo:

```
public EmpregadoContrato(Integer id, Contrato contrato) {
    this.id = id;
    // se for nulo, lança NullPointerException, caso contrário, retorna o próprio valor
    this.contrato = Objects.requireNonNull(contrato, "contrato não pode ser nulo");
}
```

O mesmo vale para o `id`. Este campo é obrigatório? Se for, remova o construtor padrão, caso contrário criará uma instância sem `id`. Só crie construtores que façam sentido (leitura sugerida: ["Para que serve um construtor?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052)).

---

Claro que, dependendo do caso, outra opção seria:

```
public EmpregadoContrato(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.contrato = new Contrato();
}
```

Aqui eu criei um contrato qualquer, só para que o campo não seja nulo. Mas você tem que avaliar se isso faz sentido: tudo bem ter um contrato "vazio" (estou supondo que a classe `Contrato` tem campos que precisam ter algum valor para representar um contrato válido)? Até porque, na classe `Contrato` valem os mesmos questionamentos: faz sentido criar um contrato sem nenhum valor setado? Ou é melhor só ter construtores que recebem as informações necessárias para se criar uma instância válida?

Você até poderia ter uma implementação diferente para um "contrato vazio", usando o [padrão Null Object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88741/112052), mas deve avaliar de acordo com o contexto se vale a pena - talvez seja melhor só ter o construtor que obriga a passar algum contrato válido.

Comment: Sua solução me atendeu plenamente. Atualizei o construtor conforme o caso abaixo e foi aceito pelo sonar. Obrigado!
public EmpregadoContrato(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.contrato = new Contrato();
}