# Evitar retorno null em métodos com retorno

Tags: c#, .net, estilo-de-codificação, return, recuperação-de-erros

O retorno externo ao laço de repetição dentro do método só será alcançado, caso não seja encontrado nenhum valor na coleção do loop. Porém não sei se retornar `null` é a solução mais recomendada, como vocês fazem pra esses casos?

OBS: Acredito que o ideal seria lançar um exception, mas não consegui implementar devido a tipagem de retorno do método.

```
public static class ContaService
{
    public static ContaBancaria? BuscarConta(List<ContaBancaria> listaContas, string numero)
    {

        foreach (var conta in listaContas)
        {
            if (conta.Numero == numero)
            {
                return conta;
            }
        }

        return null
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só você sabe o que é mais recomendado. Só você tem o contexto. O recomendado depende de contexto, porque senão vira a tal da "boa prática" que é só uma receita de bolo sem contexto para as pessoas seguirem.

Para uma resposta mais genérica pode ler [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Lá verá que retornar um `null` não tem nada de errado, se isso for relevante e não trazer problemas para o que está fazendo.

Eu nunca gosto do uso de `null`, e prefiro seu uso apenas em casos onde ele é fundamental.

Este caso fica complicado dar uma solução com algum outro tipo de código de erro. No máximo poderia criar um [`Null Object`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88741/101), o que não muda muito.

Muitas pessoas preferirão usar uma exceção por não ter achado algo. Eu sou dos que acham esta uma das piores soluções porque não achar nada é algo esperado e não excepcional. Algo assim:

```
public static ContaBancaria BuscarConta(List<ContaBancaria> listaContas, string numero) {
    foreach (var conta in listaContas) if (conta.Numero == numero) return conta;
    throw new ContaBancariaNaoExisteException(numero);
}
```

Não vou postar como seria a exceção em si.

Ou pode fazer o que eu acho mais adequado, mas o C#/.NET não tem nada padrão (por isso em várias partes dele cada tecnologia usa um padrão diferente), o que torna algo que alguns consideram alienígena, mas que resolve do jeito que deve resolver sem os problemas de cada uma das outras soluções, ainda que ela também não seja perfeita. Você usa um `Result`, algo assim:

```
public static Result<ContaBancaria> BuscarConta(List<ContaBancaria> listaContas, string numero) {
    foreach (var conta in listaContas) if (conta.Numero == numero) return Result.Success(conta);
    return Result.Failure;
}
```

Aí no lugar que recebe em vez de verificar se é nulo ou usar um `try-catch` verificará se teve sucesso. Você não consegue usar o objeto sem fazer isto, ao contrário das outras soluções, ainda que se não fizer dará um erro em algum outro lugar. Algo assim:

```
var resultado = BuscarConta(contas, numero);
if (resultado.Ok) Write(resultado.Value);
```

Dá para fazer uma `struct` `Result` simples ou [uma classe extremamente sofisticada](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults) que permite detalhar o erro, manter vários erros, vários valores, e ter muitas *features* extras. Algo assim:

Se a linguagem fosse melhor dava para fazer algo que impede o acesso em tempo de compilação. Terá como em futuras versões com o advento do ADT.

Consegue fazer a `struct`? Precisa de um campo para dizer se teve sucesso (pode ser uma propriedade), outro para o objeto que gerou o resultado (pode ser uma propriedade), e métodos de fábrica para gerar o erro ou o resultado certo, conforme mostra o código acima. Se pesquisar tem vários prontos.

Também pode usar o padrão [TryCan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) ou TesterDoer ou ainda Error Hiding, como pode ser chamado, assim não precisa criar nada extra. O jeito antigo é com [`out`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101), mas agora pode ser feito com [tupla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321968/101):

```
public static (bool Ok, ContaBancaria? conta) BuscarConta(List<ContaBancaria> listaContas, string numero) {
    foreach (var conta in listaContas) if (conta.Numero == numero) return (true, conta);
    return (false, null);
}

(var ok, var conta) = BuscarConta(contas, numero);
if (ok) Write(conta);
```

Mas eu acho que não é tão bom assim, permite o uso indevido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnError.cs).